# Compact subset of the image of a continuous function

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Given complete metric spaces $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$, a continuous function $f:X \to Y$,  and a compact subset $K \subset f(X)$, I would like to know if it is possible to claim that there exists a compact $F \subset X$ such that $K \subset f(F)$.

It seens to be right in particular cases when I suppose for instance $f$ to be bijective, and both spaces $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Any help and counterexamples would be great.

Comment: Just a remark: If $K = f(X)$ is already compact, then the question is: does there exist a compact set $F\subset X$ such that $f(F) = f(X)$.

Comment: So, here is a counterexample: Let $X = (-\infty,0]\cup [1,2]$, $Y = [0,1]$, and $f : X\to Y$ defined by $f(x) = e^x$ for $x\le 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in [1,2]$. So, you should assume at least that $X$ is connected.

Comment: You're right! We could assume for now $X = \mathbb{R}$, for example.

Comment: To prove the easier question, I started with closed balls $\overline B_n$ around a fixed point $x_0\in X$ with radius $n\in\mathbb N$. Aim: $f(\overline B_n) = Y = f(X)$ for some $n$. For this it is enough to show that each $y\in Y$ is in the interior $V_n$ of some $f(\overline B_n)$, because then, since $Y$ is compact, we have $Y = \bigcup_{k=1}^NV_s = f(\overline B_N)$. But until now I couldn't prove this. It must be somehow connected with the connectedness of each $f(\overline B_n)$. BTW, since $Y = \bigcup_nf(\overline B_n)$, we have $V_n\neq\emptyset$ for some $n$ by Baire's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only refer to the easier question:

> If $f : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous and $f(\mathbb R)$ is
>   compact, does there exist a compact set $K\subset\mathbb R$ such that
>   $f(K) = f(\mathbb R)$?

The answer is yes, if $n=1$ and no (i.e., not in general) if $n\ge 2$.

Proof for $n=1$: In this case $f(\mathbb R)$ is a compact and connected set in $\mathbb R$, hence an interval: $f(\mathbb R) = [a,b]$. Now, choose $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = a$ and $f(y) = b$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, $f([x,y]) = [a,b] = f(\mathbb R)$.

Counter example for $n=2$. Define $\phi(x) = 4\arctan(x)$ and set
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
(1+\cos(\phi(x)-\pi),\sin(\phi(x)-\pi)) &\text{if }x\ge 0,\\
(-1+\cos\phi(x),\sin\phi(x)) &\text{if }x< 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is obviously continuous and $f(\mathbb R) = C_1\cup C_{-1}$ is compact, where $C_t$ denotes the circle with center $(t,0)$ and radius $1$. But there can never be a compact $K\subset\mathbb R$ such that $f(K) = f(\mathbb R)$ since $f$ is injective.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much. And it is interesting that even if the function is injective (and so bijective in its range), your example for $n = 2$ shows that the property can not be true. ;)

Comment: Could you please check and upvote my answer? Thanks.

Comment: I checked and it seems right for me. I tried to vote but the only thing I got is   
  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @ArthurCavalcante I see. Thanks. Stupid system. ;-)